# php - finding keys in an array that match a pattern

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like:

```
 Array ( [2.5] => ABDE [4.8] => Some other value )
```

How would I find any key/value pair where the key matches a pattern?  I will know the value of the first digit in the key,but not the second. so for example, using a prefix of "2.", I want to somehow be able to find the key "2.5" and return both the key and the value "ABDE".

I was thinking about using a regular expression with a pattern like:

```
$prefix = 2;
$pattern = '/'.$prefix.'\.\d/i';
```

and then looping through the array and checking each key.  (by the way, just for demo purposes, $prefix has been hardcoded to 2, but in the real system, this is a value provided by the user's input).

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: if the prefix is dependent on user input, it can be anything, right?

Comment: Can the user enter a.a, a.* or is the user limited to 2.*, 3.*, *.5 (numbers)? And if they are limited to numbers are they limited to the tenths place? And finally are the keys ([2.5]) doubles like they appear to be or are they strings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can simply loop through the array and check the keys

```
$array = array(...your values...);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match($pattern,$key)){
        // it matches
    }
}
```

You can wrap it in a function and pass your pattern as parameter

Comment: is there any way to avoid looping?

Comment: this is not the right anwer, the right one can be found lower down, JvdBerg has the right one. There's a function in PHP specifically for finding matching keys in an array

Answer (score 63):

I think you need something like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$result = preg_grep($pattern, $keys);
```

The result will be a array that holds all the keys that match the regex. The keys can be used to retrieve the corresponding value.

Have a look at the [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but here's what I like to do:

```
$array = [ '2.5' => 'ABDE', '4.8' => 'Some other value' ];
```

`preg_grep` + `array_keys` will find all keys

```
$keys = preg_grep( '/^2\.\d/i', array_keys( $array ) );
```

You can add `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip` to extract a slice of the array that matches the pattern

```
$vals = array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip( preg_grep( '/^2\.\d/i', array_keys( $array ) ) ) );
```

Comment: The array_keys was what I needed. +1

Answer (score 3):

For future programmers who encounter the same issue. Here is a more complete solution which doesn't use any loops.

```
    $array = ['2.5'=> 'ABCDE', '2.9'=>'QWERTY'];
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $matchingKeys = preg_grep('/^2\.+/', $keys);
    $filteredArray = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($matchingKeys));
    print_r($filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

That are my ways

```
$data = ["path"=>"folder","filename"=>"folder/file.txt","required"=>false];

// FIRST WAY

$keys = array_keys($data);
if (!in_array("path", $keys) && !in_array("filename",$keys) && !in_array("required",$keys)) {
    return myReturn(false, "Dados pendentes");
}

// SECOND WAY

$keys = implode("," array_keys($data));
if (!preg_match('/(path)|(filename)|(required)/'), $keys) {
    return myReturn(false, "Dados pendentes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com/) library for regular expression in PHP, and it kas `preg::grep_keys()` method.

```php
<?php
$array = [2.5 => 'ABDE', 4.8 => 'Some other value'];

preg::grep_keys("/$prefix\.\d/i", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the part of the array with matching keys you could also write

```
$matching_array = array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_flip($your_array)));
```

This might just lead to problems performance-wise, if your array gets too big.

Comment: This will override duplicate values in `$your_array`.