# PHP Array only get those elements/values whose keys match a particular pattern

Tags: php, arrays, regex, pattern-matching, array-key

I have a multi-dimensional & nested array like below:

```
Array
(
    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1504299434:6
        )

    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )
    [additional_photos_0_gallery_image_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 77556
        )
    [additional_photos_0_gallery_image_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 77567
        )
    [additional_photos_0_gallery_image_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 73768
        )
    ....
)
```

Now I need to get only those elements of the given array(in a separate array without changing current array), whose keys match a particular pattern like below:

```
additional_photos_[any_number]_gallery_image_[any_number]
```

How can I get using one of the array functions and avoiding `foreach` loops ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482388/php-finding-keys-in-an-array-that-match-a-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use array_filter and preg_match.

```
return array_filter($data, function($key) {
    return preg_match('~^additional_photos_[0-9]+_gallery_image_[0-9]+$~', $key);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```