# Trim an array as required

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting following array on submit of the form

```
[_wpcf7] => 3
[_wpcf7_version] => 4.9.2
[_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
[_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f3-p2-o1
[_wpcf7_container_post] => 2
[your-name] => sad
[your-subject] => sad
[your-message] => sdsa
```

However I need it to be trimmed and moved to another array like

```
[your-name] => sad
[your-subject] => sad
[your-message] => sdsa
```

Actually I need to remove the contents of array

```
[_wpcf7] => 3
[_wpcf7_version] => 4.9.2
[_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
[_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f3-p2-o1
[_wpcf7_container_post] => 2
```

So please guide me how can I do it using PHP script

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Yes I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587135/copy-values-into-another-array

Comment: Is the array always in the same order?

Comment: Yes above fields are in same order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - finding keys in an array that match a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482388/php-finding-keys-in-an-array-that-match-a-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and easy :- "Remove the keys starting from `_wpcf7` and Store the remaining ones in another array"

```
<?php
    $oldArray = array(('_wpcf7') => '3',
        ('_wpcf7_version') => '4.9.2',
        ('_wpcf7_locale') => 'en_US',
        ('_wpcf7_unit_tag') => 'wpcf7-f3-p2-o1',
        ('_wpcf7_container_post') => '2',
        ('your-name') => 'sad',
        ('your-subject') => 'sad',
        ('your-message') => 'sdsa');
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($oldArray as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key,0,6) !== '_wpcf7')
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
?>
```

Check this code also :- [Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/BEGDW)
Happy Coding :-)

Comment: @Yash OP can't upvote. It's a privilege you earn. Why do you think your answer should be upvoted? As far as I know upvotes are used on good answers. This is not an answer, it's only code. If anything it should be downvoted

Comment: @Andreas Actually you are right. This is not an answer but Its far **better** than your answer. Mind one thing, answer that matters most must be simple, easy to understand and minimal code.

Comment: in what way is my answer hard to understand?

Comment: not able to find any comments with **hard to understand**. It depends on the questioner.

Comment: @YashParekh What are you talking about. I have comments to my code. It's written above the code. I'll copy it here for you: *It will first get all key names and then loop the keys backwards three times to get the last three items and save them to $namearr*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162592/discussion-between-yash-parekh-and-andreas).

Answer (score 1):

Save only desired keys in array

```
$array2 = array(
 'your-name',
 'your-subject',
 'your-message',
);

$res = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/930804)

Comment: I believe the problem is that OP does not "know" what the keys "your-name" etc. is

Comment: @Andreas In that case i don't think OP knows it's count :)

Comment: It's count? Don't get it. I just refer to the comment OP left to J. Litvaks answer. It's not a clear comment but I think it means keys are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$array2 = array(
 'your-name' => $array1['your-name'],
 'your-subject' => $array1['your-subject'],
 'your-message' => $array1['your-message'],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way I can remove the above fields as the fields you have mentioned is coming dynamically However the above fields are constant.

Answer (score 0):

if it's always the last three items (as you confirmed in comments) you can use this code.
It will first get all key names and then loop the keys backwards three times to get the last three items and save them to `$namearr`

```
$arr = ["_wpcf7" => 3,
"_wpcf7_version" => "4.9.2",
"_wpcf7_locale" => "en_US",
"_wpcf7_unit_tag" => "wpcf7-f3-p2-o1",
"_wpcf7_container_post" => 2,
"your-name" => "sad",
"your-subject" => "sad",
"your-message" => "sdsa"];

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$count = count($keys)-1;
$namearr=[];
for($i = $count; $i >$count-3;$i-- ){
    $namearr[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
var_dump($namearr);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  "your-message" => "sdsa"
  "your-subject" => "sad"
  "your-name" => "sad"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/L9Cmp