# avoid string element in php 2d array

Tags: php, yii, filtering, php-7

### Desciption:

I have an array 2d:

```
$array = InvApplication::model()->findall(array('order'=>'app_name'));
```

The array contents the next element: "app5", How to avoid it?

Actual Output:

```
app_name|field1|field2|fieldN|..|..
 appn    |
 appn1   |
 appn2   |
 app5    |
```

### Already Tested

> I have been testing with unset, in_array and strpos functions.
>   In addition to:

[php - finding keys in an array that match a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482388/php-finding-keys-in-an-array-that-match-a-pattern)

[Delete element from multidimensional-array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value)

### My actual piece of code:

This is an actual way, but is not working as I want.

```
$deleteapp = "app5";
unset($list[$deleteapp]); Test with unset or array_diff
        foreach($list as $k=>$v)
        {
            if(in_array($v,array('app5'))) unset($list[$k]);}
```

### I expect this:

```
app_name|field1|field2|fieldN|..|..
 appn    |
 appn1   |
 appn2   |
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you want exclude a app_name from  the select result 
in this case you could use a condition

```
$array = InvApplication::model()->findall(
  array("condition"=> "app_name !=  'app5'","order"=>"app_name")
);
```